# How can I make sure that two function calls are always made consecutively with multiple threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, pathos

I'm using Pathos like this:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
def foo(bar):
   fn1(bar)
   fn2(bar)

Pool().map(foo, data)
```

I want `fn1` and `fn2` to be executed as one atomic operation such that no threads can produce function calls in a sequence like `fn1, fn1, fn2, fn2`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lock like it is described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes).

```
def foo(lock, bar):
    lock.acquire()
    try:
       fn1(bar)
       fn2(bar)
    finally:
        lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    Pool().map(foo, [(l, d) for d in data])
```

But, why are you using multiprocessing if you don't want to call your function in parallel?

Comment: Please, not the OP is not using Python's multiprocessing, but rather the pathos project: http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/wiki.html

Comment: Hi I'm the `pathos` author.  There's a nice middle ground... if you use `multiprocess` instead of `multiprocessing`.  This is the library that `pathos` uses under the covers, and it provides the exact same interface as `multiprocessing`.  So, if you use `pathos` and combine it with really what's just a different interface in `multiprocess`, it's fully compatible.